# input type checkbox in html text not working

Tags: sweetalert

I have defined following dialog for sweetalert. Everything is working fine but checkbox is not appearing. Is there anything else I need to change in? 
I have searched enough but didn't find any solution which works.

Sweetalert dialog:

```
swal({   title: "Are you sure?",   text:" <form><input type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='Bike'>I have a bike<br></form> Workload will be validated by you for cbs merge! <div class='text-danger'>" +wl_name+ "</div>" ,   
                                     showCancelButton: true, type: "info",   
                                     confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   confirmButtonText: "Yes, validate it!",   cancelButtonText: "No, cancel pleaase!",   
                                     closeOnConfirm: false,   closeOnCancel: false, html:true , showLoaderOnConfirm: true},)
```

All other HTML tags are working fine..only this checkbox is not visible on sweetalert popup model.

Please let me know if you need any further informaiton.

Answer (score 4):

There's a nice way to use `checkbox` modal type in [SweetAlert2](http://sweetalert2.github.io/):

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Do you have a bike?',
  input: 'checkbox',
  inputPlaceholder: 'I have a bike'
}).then(function(result) {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire({icon: 'success', text: 'You have a bike!'});

  } else if (result.value === 0) {
    Swal.fire({icon: 'error', text: "You don't have a bike :("});

  } else {
    console.log(`modal was dismissed by ${result.dismiss}`)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Comment: what about multiple checkbox and checkbox selection ? @limonte

Comment: Not working for me. In my case, `result` would be 1 if checked, 0 unchecked.  `result.value` is not defined

Comment: @Shiji.Jiang update your SweetAlert dependency to the latest version

Answer (score 3):

SweetAlert does not support custom form inputs, but [SweetAlert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2) does :)

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/wuszhr25/63/)

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.test', function() {
    swal({   
      title: "Are you sure?",
      html: '<form><input type="checkbox">I have a bike<br></form> Workload will be validated by you for cbs merge! <div class="text-danger">test</div>',
      showCancelButton: true,
      type: "input",
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, validate it!",
      cancelButtonText: "No, cancel pleaase!",
      closeOnConfirm: true,
      closeOnCancel: true,
      showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Changing `type: "input",` to `input: 'checkbox',` should fix the styling issue. The `type` switches the modal type icon, while `input` switches the input type.